# Java code for Collatz Conjecture

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java so this explains a lot. I want to write a code that divides even numbers by 2 until the answer reaches 1. For example 16>8>4>2>1 and multiplies odd numbers by 3 and adds 1. But I've been unable to make it calculate the numbers of steps it takes to reach one. Also help me write a better code than the one I have please.

```
    package test;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner n=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a;
        System.out.println("Enter a value");
        a=n.nextInt();
        System.out.print(+a  );
        for(;;){
            if(a==1){
                break;
            }
            else if(a%2==0){
                a=a/2;
                System.out.print(a+",");
            }
            else if(a%2!=0){
                a=a*3+1;
                System.out.println(a+",");
            }
        }
        }}
```

Comment: *"But I've been unable to make it calculate the numbers of steps it takes to reach one"* A counter?

Comment: _"I've been unable to make it calculate the numbers of steps"_ -- please explain what you mean? Why are you unable to do so?

Comment: Note: There's no purpose served by the `+` in `System.out.println(+a);`

Comment: Is it proven that every number will eventually reach 1?

Comment: Example:16>8>4>2>1 the program should say "It has taken 4 steps for 16 to reach 1.